# How to change TextField value also from viewModel and other composables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

Here is MainViewModel.kt:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var fruit by mutableStateOf("") // changed only by changeFruit() method
        private set

    /** Validates and changes [fruit] and returns the result. */
    fun changeFruit(value: String): String {
        fruit = if (value == "apple") "banana" else value
        return fruit
    }

    // ...other methods that can change the fruit variable with changeFruit()...
}
```

Here is MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
import ...

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Tests5Theme {
                App()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun App() {
    val vm: MainViewModel = viewModel()

    Column {
        var fieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(vm.fruit) }
        
        Field(
            value = fieldValue,
            onValueChange = { fieldValue = it },
            onDone = { vm.changeFruit(fieldValue) }
        )

        // I know onClick could be { fieldValue = vm.changeFruit("apple") }
        // and { fieldValue = vm.changeFruit("strawberry") }
        // but what if these buttons are placed away in other composables?

        Button(onClick = { vm.changeFruit("apple") }) {
            Text(text = "Change fruit to apple")
        }
        Button(onClick = { vm.changeFruit("strawberry") }) {
            Text(text = "Change fruit to strawberry")

        }
        Text(text = "Value of MainViewModel.fruit: ${vm.fruit}")
    }
}

/**
 * When the done button of the keyboard is pressed, the focus is cleared from the field, then the onFocusChanged()
 * modifier is called, and then onDone() is called.
 *
 * @param value the value shown in the field.
 * @param onValueChange the lambda called when the field value is changed.
 * @param onDone the lambda called when the done button of the keyboard is pressed or the focus goes away.
 */
@Composable
fun Field(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onDone: () -> Unit
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = Modifier.onFocusChanged {
            if (!it.isFocused) onDone()
        },
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text, imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    )
}
```

The value of `fruit` can be changed typing in the textfield, pressing the buttons or with other methods in the Viewmodel. I can't figure out how to make `fieldValue` (the value of the textField) equal to `fruit` variable after calling the `changeFruit()` function.

Thanks in advance to whoever helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fruit` is already a state that is saved in the `viewModel`, the problem here is you're initializing another state with `remember`. Remember saves the value through the composition lifecycle, so your view is updated when `fieldValue` is set in the `onValueChange = { fieldValue = it }` lambda because setting a state triggers recomposition, but it's not updating when you set it programmatically because there is nothing to trigger the recomposition. There are 2 solutions to this:

1.You can use directly the state in the `viewModel` and don't create another redundant state with remember.

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val vm: MainViewModel = viewModel()

    Column {
        Field(
            value = vm.fruit,
            onValueChange = { vm.changeFruit(it) }
        )
    }
}
```

2.Passing a `key` to `remember` forces it to recalculate the value that it stores and this will trigger recomposition too

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val vm: MainViewModel = viewModel()
    var fieldValue by remember(key1 = vm.fruit) { mutableStateOf(vm.fruit) }

    Column {
        Field(
            value = fieldValue,
            onValueChange = { vm.changeFruit(it) }
        )
    }
}
```

An additional information for performance, passing the `value` directly to your Composable will cause recomposition in the entire parent Composable, `App()` in your case, because recomposition will start when there is a **state read** in its scope and this means redundant recompositions for your other Composables if they're not `skippable`.

```
@Composable
fun Field(
    provideValue: () -> String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = provideValue(),
        onValueChange = onValueChange
    )
}

@Composable
fun App() {
    Field(
        provideValue = { vm.fruit },
        onValueChange = { vm.changeFruit(it) }
    )
}
```

This way state will be read in the scope of the `provideValue()` lambda and **not in the parent Composable**, so recomposition will only happen for the `Field()` Composable. This's called the lambda approach and it's recommended to use it to pass frequently changing states.

Comment: The second solution with the key works well but with a problem, if `fruit` is `banana` and I write `apple` in the field, when I press done on the keyboard `fruit` is changed to `banana` but the value in the field remain `apple` because `fruit` was already `banana` (recomposition is not triggered), so I changed onDone lambda to `{ fieldValue = vm.changeFruit(fieldValue) }` and now works perfectly, thanks so much.